# Things that are common exclusively for Protestants and Oriental Orthodoxy

Tags: protestantism, oriental-orthodox

What things are common for absolutely all Protestants and Oriental Orthodoxy, yet cannot be found in the Eastern Orthodox Church (EOC) and Roman Catholic Church (RCC)?

(In my question, by "Protestants" I mean all those who don't belong to EOC, RCC or Oriental Christianity, don't mind praying to Jesus in their prayers besides praying to their Heavenly Father, and believe that the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit are One God. Therefore, those groups who may be called by others as "Protestants", but don't meet those requirements - for example, Mormons or Jehovah's Witnesses - are not included in my question).

Comment: I doubt there are any. They're several branches removed, and what they have in common will be shared by at least some of those you've excluded.

Comment: If you're defining the word "Protestants" as Christians with those particular characteristics, then those characteristics would be the things they have in common.

Comment: @4castle: "then those characteristics would be the things they have in common" - But those things are also true for RCC and EOC.

Comment: @curiousdannii: "and what they have in common will be shared by at least some of those you've excluded" - It's okay if some things are also shared by those excluded, the most important is that those things are not shared by RCC and EOC.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "Oriental Christianity"?

Comment: @Lee [Oriental Orthodox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_Orthodoxy)

Comment: @curiousdannii That should be specified in the question, preferably with a link as well.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden: It is the fourth largest communion of Christian churches, with about 76 million members worldwide. Specification hardly needed.

Comment: What sort of things in common do you mean? RC and EO accept the authority of some Church councils which OO and Protestants do not. Would that be a thing?

Comment: @davidlol - Yes! That would definitely be a thing. In fact, anything that would characterize exclusively the OO and the specified  by me Protestants - dogmas, beliefs, rituals, canons, liturgies, interpretations, etc. - will fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

The Easy simple answer to the OP is NONE.  Because the original question used words like "absolutely all Protestants", it is very difficult, maybe even impossible to answer such a broad but also strict question.    Lets just take one issue, basic Nicene Theology etc.   Most Protestants formally or informally  accept basic Classical Theology as far as the Trinity, Jesus as true God and true man hypostatic union etc.    However in recent times there has been a rethinking of such basic creedal theology, and some small groups of Biblical Fundamentalists, and Postmodern Evangelicals can be rethinking things like Arianism and Modalism (Oneness) etc.     And this diversity of opinion and thought is even more true on moral issues which have been more divided on issues regarding sexuality and relationships etc.

Comment: "However in recent times there has been a rethinking of such basic creedal theology" - Which means they are simply not included in my question.